# What is "it" in EntityDataSource's select property?

Tags: ado.net-entity-data-model

For example :

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="EntityDataSource2" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="name=AdventureWorksEntities" 
            DefaultContainerName="AdventureWorksEntities"  
            EnableUpdate="True" EntitySetName="Employee" 
            Select="" Where="it.EmployeeID = @selEmpID">
            <WhereParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="GridView1" Name="selEmpID" Type="Int32" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
            </WhereParameters>
</asp:EntityDataSource>
```

Is the "it" generate by EntityDataSource?
The "it" is the entity alias of Employee, but how can i define that?

For exmaple, if i include other entity by property below :

```
Include="Users,Permissions"
```

How to define different alias to different entity
e.g.:

> emp = Employee usr = Users perm =
>   Permissions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"it" is the "Control Variable."  You can change it using ObjectQuery's Name property.

ObjectQuery is what you get, for example out of your ObjectContext class, such as context.Products or context.Customers.

```
var query = context.Products;
query.Name = "products";  // changes "it" to "products"
```

Comment: Can you cite documentation on this?  Your answer is helpful but I'd like to know where my MSDN research efforts went awry...

Comment: @pseudocoder - I learned about "it" from [Julia Lehrman's EF book](http://books.google.com/books?id=rtdgHbMeTBMC&pg=PA65&lpg=PA65&dq=it+%22control+variable%22+entity+framework&source=bl&ots=kVskZwHwXA&sig=4tstuqUS5VMlce_hxSj48Rg39OA&hl=en&sa=X&ei=TWYgUMKqC5CO8wS2gYFg&ved=0CEUQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=it%20%22control%20variable%22%20entity%20framework&f=false).  [Here it is on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347374.aspx).

Comment: I have heard good things about that book, thanks so much for the reference!

Comment: No problem.  If you're thinking about buying it, I'd recommend that you wait until she updates it for the new(ish) Code-First workflow.